# What's the correct Xpath substring for selecting date in a phrase?

Tags: xpath, substring

I need to use Xpath to select the date from the following string:

44kb - Mr John Doe - 1/1/13

I don't believe you can select the third iteration of the '-' for something like

```
substring-after($string, '-'[3])
```

How would I do this?  Is there a way to grab the substring from the space before the first '/' to the end of the date?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If there are just two dashes, as in the provided example, one can simply use this XPath 1.0 expression**:

```
substring-after(substring-after('44kb - Mr John Doe - 1/1/13', '- '), '- ')
```

**If it is known that the date is what the string ends with, and that the length of the date is 6, then one can use**:

```
substring('44kb - Mr John Doe - 1/1/13', string-length('44kb - Mr John Doe - 1/1/13') -5)
```

**Alternatively**:

```
translate(substring('44kb - Mr John Doe - 1/1/13', 
                    string-length('44kb - Mr John Doe - 1/1/13') -7),
         '- ', '')
```

Here we don't know the length of the date in advance, so we take the last 8 characters and in these we delete any dashes or spaces.

Comment: This worked.  I had to mess with the length of the string but it did the trick.  Just so I understand the three things going on here:  string-length is giving me a numerical value for the length of the included string.  Substring -7 is giving me ....the latter portion of the string....the last eight positions in the string...?  And translate removes the dashes or spaces?  Thanks for the help Dimitre!!

Comment: @rally_point, Yes, basically, your understanding is correct: in case we don't know in advance the actual length of the date, we take the maximum possible length(8) and delete from this substring any dashes or spaces. It is also possible to delete from this string any non-digit and non-slash characters, but this is a little bit more complicated (the "double-translate" method).

Answer (score 2):

`fn:substring-after(...)` only splits once, so you will have to apply it twice.

```
substring-after(substring-after('44kb - Mr John Doe - 1/1/13', ' - '), ' - ')
```

If your XPath processor supports it (at least XPath 2.0), you can also use `fn:tokenize(...)` to split to all parts and then use a position predicate to fetch the third one.

```
tokenize("44kb - Mr John Doe - 1/1/13", ' - ')[3]
```

If the number of parts can vary, but the date is always the last one, you can also use

```
tokenize("44kb - Mr John Doe - 1/1/13", ' - ')[last()]
```

which always matches the last part.

Comment: I can't use a 2.0 Xpath processor, but your first example, made me smack my forehead.  Just nesting two substring-after functions.  I should have realized that would work. Of course if there were examples where there were three dashes in the string, this wouldn't grab them but I haven't ran into any of those.  Thanks!